# iPad restarting every 5 minutes after updating to iOS 9

Tags: ipad, restart, ios

After the update on iOS 9, iPad 3 with Cellular Model A1430 itself is restarting after 5 minutes. I made hard reset but it didn't help me. I didn't drop my iPad. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use iTunes to update it to iOS 9.0.1, which just came out today and fixes a lot of problems with the original release.

Comment: I updated my iPad on iOS 9.0.1 and it solved my problem!